# Exclude marker from clustering Google Maps Android API Utility Library on Android?

Tags: android, marker

I am using Google Maps Android Utility Library adding objects/markers in ClusterManager, but I would like to exclude/add some markers that are not in Cluster. I was able to add markers on map using `googleMap.addMarker()` without clustering but the problem is that I have to handle `OnInfoWindowClickListener` which is registered with `ClusterManager` so I can register the click on excluded Markers.

Is there a possibility to combine `ClusterManager` from Utility Library with some markers that are not in cluster and register `OnInfoWindowClickListener` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but this should work:

- create class extending `ClusterManager`
- override `onInfoWindowClick` and call `super.onInfoWindowClick`
- check if `Marker` sent to you as a parameter is the one you added via `GoogleMap.addMarker`
- do your stuff

If you are not happy with a code like that, [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) has such a functionality built in with a call to

```
marker.setClusterGroup(ClusterGroup.NOT_CLUSTERED);
```

Comment: Tnx a lot for your help , I have done as you suggested extending the ClusterManager class.. and now I am able to exclude markers from cluster and register on infoWindowClick for them. Regards.

Comment: @MaciejGórski I'm not that experienced Java developer. Could you provide a more detailed example? I was also able to add the marker directly, but I did not figure out how to receive the click events for that specific item I've added with addMarker.